# Changing folder directory from SSD to HD

Tags: windows-10, folder-redirection

In my pc i have a ssd and a hard disk, I wanted to change the document folder's directory to be in the hard disk instead of the ssd. I mistakenly set the whole disk D: (the hard disk) as the document directory, and now I can't change it. If I try to change the directory to another folder inside of D it says that it can't change from father to son, and if I try to change it to a directory in C it tries to copy everything inside of D into C. How can I solve this? I want to set a specific directory as the directory of the document folder.

Comment: Right click on the document folder in Explorer _this PC_  window. Go to _Location_ tab and change the path.

Comment: @biswa already tried, it gives me the errors that I talked about in the question

Comment: Then make a directory symbolic link.